# .htaccess for nested React App within subfolders

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to host two React app nested within subfolders, with redirects using .htaccess.

I don't have access to the .htaccess on the root folder

Here is my directory structure -

```
html/
├─ react-app-1/
│  ├─ react-app-2/
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  ├─ .htaccess
│  ├─ .htaccess
│  ├─ index.html
├─ other_subfolders_with_websites/...
```

`react-app-1` with Router works just fine with `.htaccess` from react-documentation

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

But, whenever I go to `www.example.com/react-app-1/react-app-2`, I want `react-app-2` to serve it's index.html, but the URL is forwarded to Router of `react-app-1`.

I have tested lots of RewriteRules and RedirectMatch, but every other rule crashes `react-app-1`.

Please suggest RewriteRules for `.htaccess` to accomplish this.

Thank you.

Tried multiple .htaccess rules with RewriteCond, RewireRule and RedirectMatch, but every other rules crashes `react-app-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

you send all request to react-app1/index in react-app1/.htaccess
you can use one htaccess file in root project :

```
#first send sepeficted react-app-2 request to react app2
RewriteRule ^react-app-2$ react-app-2/index.html [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^react-app-2$/(.*) react-app-2/index.html [QSA,L]

#if request is not for react app2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```